# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (using <img>)

Tags: html

I try to display an image using ' img html tag ' into my page (index.html)
The image is in the folder (imgs) inside my project folder (Book_Store)
I can't success and i am facing this error message

```html
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

[The code in visual studio code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bdemf.jpg)

[The output in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Y5vL.jpg)

[Inside my project folder (Book_Store)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nh2mT.jpg)

[Inside the folder (imgs)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3ZZ9.jpg)

What I did wrong ?
Thank You In Advance

Comment: did you try this with any other image?

Comment: Yes I did and I faced the same problem.

Comment: okay then try placing the image in same folder as your index.html file

Comment: try using `./imgs` instead of just `imgs`

Comment: or you could try using the full path of your image in src attribute like this = <img src="D:\Book_Store\imgs\parameter-vs-argument.png" />

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please correct your formatting. Please don't use code snippets for error logs, but instead put the code in code snippets, not images. Please also use images instead of links for images for the actual images. Many people may be trying to help, but their network may be blocking/be blocked by imgur, so they cannot access and help. It is also much better to have code as code blocks because it is easier to read and copy/paste for testing, instead of having to type it all out. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Jakyb Korts Thank You Very Much  ./imgs worked successfully.

Comment: Jakyb Korts When I tried to use the full path I faced the same problem. but ./imgs it works.

Answer (score 0):

please try changing img src to

```
   <img src="./imgs/parameter-vs-argument.png" alt=""></img>
```

and let me know if this worked

Comment: Thank You Very Much. It works but I must to write ./imgs then select the image. When I tried to write the path without selecting it doesn't work. I dont't know why !

Comment: `<img>` tags do not close.